# I lost my Pro Tools 9 Installation disc, can someone help?

Tags: pro-tools

Does anyone have a link to download the installation files for windows? Or might someone have an .img file or something they could send me? I'm not looking for a cracked version, I do own an iLok with a Pro Tools 9 license on it, I just need the installation files.

I know the Avid website has a way to download this, but my version of Pro Tools did not come with the activation code required, I only have a registration code.

Answer (score 3):

Avid provides replacement disks from their online store.  You can access it [here](https://shop.avid.com/ccrz__Products?cartID=&categoryId=a3yi0000000012RAAQ&parentCategory=a3yi0000000011wAAA&g=&&store=shop).  You could try contacting them to see if there is a download option, but it is possible they may only provide physical media for boxed copies.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear there is a legal way to download Pro-Tools 9 from the AVID website. Sorry.

You can contact the support and explain the problem to them to see if they can help, at this link:

http://www.avid.com/US/support/support-contact

In the future make sure that you register your software. 
Additionally you can fully legally make an additional copy of the installation disc for your use only, and keep the original stored safely.